# How can an ASP.NET MVC server over IIS push notification to its clients?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, push-notification

I know ASP.NET MVC and IIS, but know nothing about push notification. Can someone point me to some introduction material, which starts with the very fundamental mechanism? I can easily find a lot of tutorial which start with coding, but without knowing the fundamental mechanism behind it I felt very difficult.

BACKGROUND: We have a server in the cloud, and thousands of hardware devices running **firmware written in C/C++**, each maintaining a TCP socket with the server all the time. The design intent is so that the server can instantly send commands to the devices. But this architecture makes it difficult/impossible to scale using ready-made technologies such as AWS load balancer and auto scaling group. I am looking at possibility to turn this architecture into a loosely connected architecture, in which the server and the hardware devices communicate with each other using standard web API and push notifications.

Comment: You might want to learn about SignalR

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will the firmware on the simple device, written in C or C++, be able to harness the SignalR API?